# Windows service properties.settings.default location?

Tags: windows-7, windows-services, app-config, properties.settings

I have built a Windows service app that's installed and running. During debugging while the service is running, I have found that when I import the properties.settings.default and modify it, it is not saved to the app.config file in my project folder. I could not find this app.config file in [user]/%appdata%/Local/ either..

Where does properties.settings.default.save() save to?
I'm running Windows 7 if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the APPDATA folder for system accounts at:

```
C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile
```

Or (for x86 apps on Win7 64):

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile
```

Comment: I just updated my post.  X86 apps will go to SysWow64 I believe